# throwTo warp tls thread hangs idefinetly

Tags: multithreading, haskell, ghc, haskell-warp

I have a Yesod app with a warp server, and some of its functionality depends on async exceptions. Recently there arose a need to migrate it to https, which I did with the package `warp-tls`. However now I can't kill the warp thread by throwing `ThreadKilled` exceptions at it, the `throwTo` function just hangs and does nothing.

Consider the following example. Here we monitor the state of warp thread with `MVar ()`, which is empty while the thread is running, and has a () value when the thread is killed.

```hs
import MyApplication (waiPage)
-- waiPage :: Application

runWai :: MVar () -> IO ()
runWai finishVar = bracket
  (return ())
  (const $ putMVar finishVar ())
  (const runApp)
  where
    -- change this to normal or tls to check
    runApp = runAppTls
    runAppNormal = runSettings warpSettings waiPage
    runAppTls = runTLS siteTlsSettings warpSettings waiPage
    --
    warpSettings = setPort 8080 defaultSettings
    siteTlsSettings = tlsSettings "cert.pem" "key.pem"



main :: IO ()
main = do
  finishVar <- newEmptyMVar
  thread_id <- forkIO $ runWai finishVar
  -- Try to kill warp thread. Fork because throw might hang
  forkIO $ throwTo thread_id ThreadKilled
  threadDelay (2 * 10^6) -- microseconds to seconds
  isAlive <- isEmptyMVar finishVar
  if isAlive then putStrLn "Couldn't kill warp thread"
             else putStrLn "Succesfully killed warp thread"
  -- Wait for forked warp thread to finish
  readMVar finishVar
```

When you have `runApp = runAppNormal`, you will get `Succesfully killed warp thread` message, and the application will exit.

When you have `runApp = runAppTls`, you will get the `Couldn't kill warp thread` message, and the app will hang and keep serving.

So how do I get rid of this exception-intercepting behavior? Or at Least is there a way to kill the warpTls thread in any other way?

Comment: What happens if you connect to the server after it hangs?

Comment: ``bracket (return ()) (const $ putMVar finishVar ()) (const runApp) <=> runApp `finally` (putMVar finishVar ())``

Comment: @freestyle It's the throwing thread that hangs, the serving thread still serves web pages as if nothing was thrown. And thanks for noting about `finally`, that's a bad adaptation of code into question on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a Windows-only bug in the version I used which is `warp-tls == 3.2.4` that got fixed in a later version. I've looked at the fix and it's a function with the name `windowsThreadBlockHack`, so if anyone is stuck with a bit outdated warp, you can backport this fix for you too.